# How do I add an Animation Offset to a Looped Curve Trim

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

This is in some ways a continuation of this [Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281593/how-do-i-create-a-consistent-loop-using-trim-curve-map-range-and-modulo).

I have created a looping curve trim animation.

[image]

I need to be able to control the movement speed and the time between loops. The speed works fine, however any change to the length of the curve it is based on (blue), and the offset changes drastically. (The divide node is 12/5)

For clarification: I want to be able to precisely control the offset of each loop regardless of the blue curve's length. The goal is to give it a number, say 30, and get a 30 frame delay till the next loop. Currently changing especially the length of the blue curve will change the delay by a drastic amount.

An example: with the  length of 5m and a value of 1 in the Loop Offset node, the delay is about 12 frames. If I increase the value to 20 the Offset is about 22 Frames. However if I increase the length of the blue curve to 10m, at an Offset value of 1 the delay is 36 frames and at a value of 20 the delay is 46 frames.

[image]

[image: Node Group]

I may not be going about this in the in the best way, so any improvements are welcome.

This is the complete set-up:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i love answering GN questions....but only if i do not have to rebuild the node tree manually. So if you would provide the blend file, i will take a look...

Comment: @Chris Sure thing, I cleaned it up a bit too

Comment: i don't quite understand. The node called "node offset" controls the offset. So i don't understand what you mean!? Maybe can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Chris I added some more info, hope that helps. The Offset node does indeed seem to be working, the real major problem is varying results based on the increase of the Curve length.